# Implementing the following series?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, series

I am trying to implement the following series with a following for-loop and x=1, but am not getting the desired result, could someone please specify where I am going wrong?

I have attached an image of the series as follows:

[image]

```
x = 1;
for k = 1:21
    S(k) = (2./sqrt(2*pi))*(cumsum((x.^(2*(k-1)-1)*(-1.^((k-1)+2)))./((2.^(k-1))*(factorial(k-1))*(2*(k-1)+1))))
end
```

For some reason, I am getting completely different results as my number is negative, but I have looked over my code over again but Im still not sure where its coming from.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indexing is out. At the opening of the `cumsum` statement you put

`x.^(2*(k-1)-1)`

Which should be . .

`x.^(2*(k-1)+1)`